# Looking for a good set of earbuds similar to these ones with large speakers

Tags: audio, speakers, wearable-technology, earphones

[image: earbuds]

I love the one on the right in this image, the speaker is quite large and it sounds great. I've had these earbuds for years but they're starting to fall apart on me, so I'm looking to replace them. However, I can't seem to find any of the same style. I absolutely *despise* the "ergonomic" earbuds that go deep into your ear, I simply want earbuds with large speakers that rest outside your ear. Also, the audio quality needs to be decently good, and it needs to be a 3.5mm headphone jack.

Comment: Both of the earbuds depicted are made by Apple. Why not just purchase another pair of Apple earbuds?